# Span text on separate lines using css

Tags: css

I have some text I want to be positioned inside a holder as follows:

```
[...........]
[.the]......]
[.[title]...]
[...........]
```

The holder needs to have a black background and I'd like the text to have a white background and black text. I am using the following structure:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="title">
        <span>The</span>
        <span>Title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if it's correct or not, but I am using the `<span>s` over `<p>s` becuase the p was going full width of the holder whereas the width of the span sizes itself to the text itself.

I want each span on a new line and this is where it is breaking atm. Currently the spans just sit on the same line together. I tried adding a `<br>` after the first span but that doesn't fix it either, this time the second span is slightly below but positioned to the right.

The css I am using:

```
.holder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.title span {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use float for that.
Moreover, span was created to span text in the middle of the line.

Is that what you were trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhjtv/ ?

Comment: But I'd like the white background to only fit around the word inside the divs. Aha got it: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhjtv/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clear:both;` to the style declarations for your spans.

If this does not solve your problem, than please build an example on http://www.jsfiddle.net so wie can better understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your line siting one after another you should use divs

Answer (score 0):

just try removing float:left; from

```
.title span {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

separate the lines by using the css word-break

click here view the result
http://gucoders.com/css3/css_wordbreak.php

Comment: try to avoid paste links as answer